# Elastic Spring Data OR Java High Level REST Client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm new to both Elasticsearch and Spring. I've written a Javascript POC that converts a JSON string into an Elasticsearch query (and performs the request). 
It takes a string like this:

```
{
    "period": "years",
    "format": "xml",
    "criteria": {
        "operator": "OR",
        "operands": [
            {
                "operator": "AND",
                "operands": [
                    {
                        "operator": "exists",
                        "field": "def"
                    },
                    {
                        "operator": "includes",
                        "field": "keywords",
                        "value": [
                            "abcd"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "operator": "AND",
                "operands": [
                    {
                        "operator": "from",
                        "field": "links",
                        "value": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "operator": "includes",
                        "field": "keywords",
                        "value": [
                            "abcd",
                            "efgh"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

(Note: This query may have any levels of nesting)

... and converts it into this:

```
{
    "query": {
      "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "exists": {
                              "field": "def"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "range": {
                              "effectiveDate": {
                                "gte": 1543982400,
                                "lt": 1575518400
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "terms": {
                              "keywords.name": [
                                "abcd",
                                "efgh"
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "range": {
                              "effectiveDate": {
                                "gte": 1543982400,
                                "lt": 1575518400
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": {
                          "terms": {
                            "links": [
                              11048,
                              34618,
                              34658
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "terms": {
                              "keywords.name": [
                                "abcd",
                                "efgh"
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "range": {
                              "effectiveDate": {
                                "gte": 1543982400,
                                "lt": 1575518400
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
      "by_id": {
        "composite": {
          "sources": [
            {
              "agg_on_id": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "id"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "size": 10000,
          "after": {
            "agg_on_id": -1
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "latest_snapshot": {
            "top_hits": {
              "sort": [
                {
                  "effectiveDate": "desc"
                }
              ],
              "_source": true,
              "size": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It first creates a query (similar to above) for a first trip to Elasticsearch to extract some info ('links') needed for building this query. 
Each trip to Elasticsearch may return millions of results, so it does paging using the "search_after" mechanism.
I need to convert this POC to a Spring application.

**Question**: Which one is most appropriate for this case - Spring Data Elasticsearch or Elasticsearch Java High Level REST Client? 
Spring data elasticsearch seems to do a good job at creating simple queries without much effort, but would it help me in this case?
Any suggestions are be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data Elasticsearch uses the high level client provided by Elasticsearch for the non-reactive implementation.

You can use the query builders from Elasticsearch together with Spring Data Elasticsearch too, this gives you the greatest flexibility.

Spring Data Elasticsearch puts on top of that the entity mapping (POJO to JSON), repository functions  and the other stuff from Spring Data.
So it's not a question if you should do the one or the other, but if you need or want to use the additional functionality that Spring Data Elasticsearch offers.

**Edit:**

When using Spring Data Elasticsearch, you configure the used `RestHighLevelClient` (see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest)) and then have it injected into your other Spring beans. So you can even mix access to ES using Spring Data `ElasticsearchOperations` or Repositories and access by using the `RestHighLevelClient` directly.

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly, Spring is helpful with regards to the response in that it provides SearchHit<T> and SearchHits<T>, but if what you're interested in is the results in the aggregation part, you still have to write code to parse that part of the response, correct? [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.0.RC1/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations.searchresulttypes)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the [official Java-high-level rest-client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html) which is being worked on actively at Elastic and you can also look at all [the queries builders](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-query-builders.html) it supports(it has got query builders for almost all the queries ).

Also previously Elasticsearch didn't have an official client for JAVA but now as they have and actively improving and developing, IMHO you should go ahead with them as it also provides a lot of out of box options and who understand Elasticsearch better than the company behind it :)

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch uses the Rest Highlevel client from Elasticsearch and it uses the Elasticsearch query builders.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch thanks for the comment, great and would the user of spring-data-es will be able to use the rest-high level client directly if they want, I guess the answer would be yes, just wanted to confirm as you are the committer  of spring-data:)